# SSIS Dynamic Columns

Tags: sql-server, ssis, dynamic-sql

I created variables that are populated from rows from another table. It should loop through each row to generate my next select statement. However, SSIS isn't accepting `'+ @[User::ThisField]+'` as a variable it expects `AS MyColName` after. I don't want this because it will return the column name and not the actual value it contains.

This is my code.

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL('+ (DT_I4)@[User::ThisID]+', 0) AS EEDFID, 
    '+ @[User::ThisField]+', 
    EeID
FROM 
    EeExtraDetails
```

Has anyone had luck with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not going to work that way. Assuming all the @[User::ThisField] data types are the same, then your problem is just how to use expressions.  If the value of @ThisField is Col1 and it's numeric and then @ThisField becomes Col2 which is text, the data flow will fails as the metadata cannot change at runtime.

### My metadata doesn't change, explain the expressions part

Variables don't work into queries the way you have it now, but you're on the correct path. Instead, define a new variable `@[User::QuerySource]`, data type of String and specify that the value is an Expression.  Your expression then becomes much as you have it now.

```
"SELECT ISNULL("
+ (DT_WSTR, 20)@[User::ThisID]
+ ", 0) AS EEDFID, "
+ @[User::ThisField] 
+ " AS MyFieldAlias "
+ ", EeID FROM EeExtraDetails "
```

The string concatenation within the SSIS expression language only works with strings so I have explicitly cast your @User::ThisID as string. If I misinterpreted that and you were intending to use the SSIS Expression language's ISNULL function, then that's a different syntax. At any rate, click evaluate and you should see whether your query looks approximately correct for the design-time values.

### My metadata does change

The best you can do in this situation is cast the results of @[User::ThisField] to string within the SQL Statement like

```
+ "CAST(", @[User::ThisField, " AS nvarchar(4000))"
```